# UPDATE TABLE with dynamic COLUMN name

Tags: java, sql, dynamic, sql-update

I have a dynamic number of data values in an array fetched from an HTML form.

Now I want to update my table with these data.
The column names are `column1` , `column2` ... and so on;
I have data in the `array[]` and number of columns to update in `unumber`
I am using this code but its not working.
P.S: I am new to coding so it might be naive.

```
for(int i=1; i<=unumber; i++)
{
        String username = "someuser";
        String column = "column" + Integer.toString(i);
        PreparedStatement pr = null;
        String query1 = "update table1 set (?) = (?) where username = (?)";
        pr = con.prepareStatement(query1);
        pr.setString(1, column);
        pr.setString(2, array[i]);
        pr.setString(3, someuser);
        int s = pr.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: As a quick heads up, you're not doing an ALTER on a table, as that keyword carries a very different meaning. You're updating fields on a row, totally different matter

Comment: You can not use parameters for identifiers in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PreparedStatment`s can only bind values, not syntactic elements or object names, like columns, so this approach won't work. You'll have to fall back to string manipulation:

```
for(int i=0; i<unumber; i++) {
        String username = "someuser";
        String column = "column" + Integer.toString(i);;
        PreparedStatement pr = null;
        String query1 = "update table1 set " + column + " = (?) where username = (?)";
        pr = con.prepareStatement(query1);
        pr.setString(1, column);
        pr.setString(2, someuser);
        int s = pr.executeUpdate();
}
```

Moreover, since you're updating several columns with the same where clause, you could loop over the columns and construct just **one** update statement. It will force you to have two loops (one for constructing the query and one for binding the values once the query is prepared), but it should still be considerably faster, as you're accessing the database only once instead of N times:

```
String username = "someuser";
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("update table1 set ");
for(int i=0; i < unumber; i++) {
    sql.append("column")
       .append(i).
       .append(" = ?");
    if (i != (unumber - 1)) {
        sql.append(", ");
    }
}
sql.append("where username = (?)");

PreparedStatement pr = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

for(int i = 0; i < unumber; i++) {
    pr.setString(i, array[i]);
}
pr.setString(unumber, someuser);
int s = pr.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, you can't use "prepared statements" for this. You can resolve it by performing the insertion in the query yourself:

```
String query1 = "update table1 set "+column+" = ? where username = ?";
    pr = con.prepareStatement(query1);
    pr.setString(1, array[i]);
    pr.setString(2, someuser);
```

But **be aware of sql injection**. You better check whether the possible values of column can't be altered. **Validate all input that leads to determining the column name**.

Make sure a user can't specify the column his/herself: otherwise one could for instance set the column to `password` and set a password for some user. And then login with that password. Or one could try to set the `column` to `'; drop table foo; select * where x`

Comment: @JBNizet: indeed, that was an error I've made. Thanks for noticing it.